# How to align responsive image side by side with table

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have one table on the right side and i want to have an image on the left side aligned with the table.
The problem is that when resize the page, the image size dosen't follow the table.

```css
.div-contains{
    background-image: url("http://www.castan.pt/castan/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/img-teste-02.jpg");
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.div-forum{
    overflow-x:auto;
    background-color:white;
    width:75%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;

}
tr{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div-contains" >
      <div class="div-forum" >
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have table and image syde by side and when someone resize screen both have the same size.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFkXr.png

Comment: Im not seeing any images in your code...we can help if you can be more indepth

Comment: the image is on the css.


div-contains{
background-image: url("http://www.castan.pt/castan/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/img-teste-02.jpg");
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

Comment: oh Background Image! lol that helps...why dont you just have it as an image file instead of background? and if you want to keep it as background than you have to play with the background-size and position

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Right now your image is used as a background and the table partially overlaps it. Not sure what you mean by "both have the same size".

Comment: i want this :
https://imgur.com/lMNkOdi.png

And when i resize screen both (table and image) stays proportional

Comment: You still do not explain why do you put image in background and not in `img` tag. Is it a must ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must set image as background and set it on the right, here you go:

In your `div-contains` set this property:

```css
background-size: 25%; /* From a 100% set 25% as your table width take 75% */
background-position: right; /* set it to the right */
```

### DEMO

```css
.div-contains{
    background-image: url("http://www.castan.pt/castan/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/img-teste-02.jpg");
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 25%; /* From a 100% set 25% as your table width take 75% */
    background-position: right; /* set it to the right */
}
.div-forum{
    overflow-x:auto;
    background-color:white;
    width:75%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;

}
tr{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="div-contains" >
      <div class="div-forum" >
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
              <td>yrdyr</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```